# Mobile authenticaion Failed in wso2

Tags: wso2

The error I got says:

> Device Registration gives an error, Authentication Failed, Contact Administrator 
>   in WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

We need more information to analyze this issue further. However I recommend you to download and test the latest EMM release [1].

[1]. http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/

Thanks,